# Why Does Adding Bytes in Different Ways Give Different Results?

Tags: c#

Could anyone explain it to me that how output of `Console.WriteLine(a);` equals to 44 in this code block.

```cs
byte a = 200;
byte b = 100;
var c = a + b;
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType());  // output: System.Int32
Console.WriteLine(c);  // output: 300

a += b;
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 44
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Perhaps we could be more helpful if you can tell us what you expected it to output.

Comment: That code doesn't compile... `**a` is not legal c# syntax. Also, it seems there are a lot of irrelevant lines of code there?

Comment: 200 + 100 = 300 which exceeds the maximum value a `byte` can hold and ends up as 300 - 256 = 44, per modular arithmetic.

Comment: The result of `byte+byte` is - against what you might expect - `int`, so: it can't overflow; but `byte += byte` retains the `byte`-ness, so: overflows

Comment: Others have answered your question, but if you want your numbers to add up, then you need a larger type, like `int`, or `long` which hold much larger numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```cs
a += b;
```

Is equivalent to this line:

```cs
a = (byte) (a + b);
```

... except that `a` is only evaluated once. The result of `a + b` is of type `int` (with a value of 300 in this case), and the cast to `byte` truncates that to 8 bits (the size of the `byte` type), leaving a result of 44.

From section 12.18.3 of the ECMA C# 5 standard:

> An operation of the form `x op= y` is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution (§12.4.5) as if the operation was written `x op y`. Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as `x = x op y`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the type of `x`, and if `y` is implicitly convertible to the type of `x` or the operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x op y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, the compound assignment is invalid, and a binding-time error occurs.

Comment: @Neil: If they want to only read the first part, that doesn't include the spec, they can do so - I think the first part is fairly easy to understand. I've added a tiny bit more explanation, but I think it's already pretty reasonable. You can add your own answer to explain it differently of course.